# How to read data from two text files and merge them into one matrix?

Tags: octave

I am dealing with two text files "sample01.txt" (https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=10B030792EBE268A&id=10B030792EBE268A%21903&parId=root&o=OneUp) and sample02.txt (https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=10B030792EBE268A&id=10B030792EBE268A%21904&parId=root&o=OneUp). 
In the first "sample01.txt" there are two columns. One is for T[K] and another one is for mole concentration for species. In "sample01.txt" data for 3 species (NC7H16,O2 and CO) are piled vertically.
On the other file "sample02.txt" all the columns are arranged side by side with only one T[K] column which is common for all the species.
In the image file "Composed_matrix_sample01_sample02.png" (https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=10B030792EBE268A&id=10B030792EBE268A%21906&parId=root&o=OneUp) shows how I want to merge data from two files. For example, if there are three species (in "sample01.txt") I want to have three matrices like the sample that I provided in "Composed_matrix_sample01_sample02.png".

So far I read the two files from the directory and identified the row numbers where the vertically pile data in "sample01.txt" needs to be spitted. But based on those row number I don't know how to split the long column and extract data (T[K] and mole concentration) for each species.

```
% full path to files (I prefer working with full paths but you could    just use filenames)
clear all
clc
s1 =  fullfile('/home/ali/Desktop/test_JSR', 'sample01.txt'); 
s2 =  fullfile('/home/ali/Desktop/test_JSR', 'sample02.txt'); 
% Read sample02 (this one's simple)
s2Table = dlmread(s2,'',1,0);  
% Read sample01; it will be read in as a cell array of strings
fid = fopen(s1); 
s1str = textscan(fid, '%s %s', 'HeaderLines', 1);
fclose(fid);
s1str = [s1str{:}]; 
% Now separate each sub-table into it's own table
key = 'T[K]';                           %the start of each row that identifies a new sub-table
headerIdx = strcmp(s1str(:,1), key);  %logical index identifying header rows
```

I want to merge the T[k] and mole concentration columns in "sample01.txt" with the T[k] and mole concentration columns in "sample02.txt" for the corresponding species. And create matrix like "Composed_matrix_sample01_sample02.png" for each species. In this case there are three species (NC7H16,O2 and CO) so I want a loop that will provide the desired merged matrix one after another.

N.B: 01. Species number in both text files will be always same. However, length of column for species in sample01.txt and sample02.txt may vary and I expect to pad the empty cell with "911911911" which I will remove later. 
 02. Number of species is not fixed so a versatile approach is needed which will cover any number of species.

Comment: put the examples of the files in the question. Not everyone has Onedrive.

Comment: Please [edit] your original question in the form of a [mcve]